# I am trying to make a discord bot with python rewrite that changes a channel permissions after every 24 hrs or everyday at a specific time

Tags: python, loops, python-asyncio, background-task

I am able to change the channel permissions with a command but I want to loop it so that the bot automatically changes permissions. I don't know how.

This is what I have written so far , it can change the permissions but how do I automate it?

````
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def lock(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    guild = client.get_guild(702178772333494412)
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = '┃➥┃Member')
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False)
    test_e = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Colour.green()
    )
    test_e.add_field(name="**Announcement:-**", value="Registration is now Closed!", inline=True)
    
    await ctx.send(embed=test_e)


@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def unlock(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    guild = client.get_guild(702178772333494412)
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = '┃➥┃Member')
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(role, send_messages=True)
    test_e = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Colour.blue()
    )
    test_e.add_field(name="**Announcement:-**", value="Registration is now open!", inline=True)
    
    await ctx.send(embed=test_e)
    ```
````

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problem(s) are you having?

Comment: You can use discord.py's built in tasks to automate loops and have it run every x time

Comment: Use [sleep_until from the discord docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#utility-functions)